# Using an Array declared in a XAML resource

Tags: c#, xaml

My goal is to retrieve an `ObservableCollection<Color>` out of a XAML resource file, but I'm using .NET 3.5 so I can't directly declare the generic type in XAML.  My current solutions is to declare a Color array in XAML:

```
<x:Array Type="Color" x:Key="ColourPickerStandardColours">
    <Color>#974806</Color>
    <Color>#FF0000</Color>
    <Color>#FFC000</Color>
    ...
    <Color>#7030A0</Color>
</x:Array>
```

and retrieve it in code:

```
var standardColours = new ObservableCollection<Color>(
    (Color[])TryFindResource("ColourPickerStandardColours"));
```

When I try to run this though, I get this exception:

```
InvalidCastException
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Markup.ArrayExtension' to type
    'System.Windows.Media.Color[]'.
```

ArrayExtension has `IList Items`, but I need the generic `IEnumerable<T>` to construct an `ObservableCollection<T>`.  I think I could use `ProvideValue(IServiceProvider)`, but I'm not sure what I should pass to it.

Am I doing something wrong, or just missing something obvious?

Comment: Just use `Items.Cast<Color> ()`.

Comment: ...And I feel like an idiot now.  Thanks.  If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPF uses an untyped collection there. Just use `Items.Cast<Color> ()`.

Answer (score -1):

Cast to ArrayExtension, and your values are in the Items property

Comment: Unfortunately I need a generic collection to construct the ObservableCollection, and `Items` is just `IList`.  Anton Tykhyy was correct with `.Cast<Color>()`.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin why do you need a generic collection?  You don't even need to load into an ObservableCollection.  You can bind to the IList directly - it isn't going to change.

Comment: The control I'm using takes an `ObservableCollection<ColorItem>` (`ColorItem` is easy to construct from `Color`). I included notes about why I couldn't use `.Items` in the question, but didn't think I would need to go into massive detail describing the reasons behind my requirements.